# Replace Raid 5 HDD with a non empty HDD

Tags: raid, raid5

Is it safe to replace a corrupt HDD (HDD-A) inside a Raid 5 array (enterprise class hardware) with an almost full disk which contains almost the same data as the corrupt disk (HDD-B)?
Will the new drive (HDD-B) always be considered as empty while the rebuild is done or could this create inconsistencies?
HDD-B is from PC-B which is clone of PC-A where HDD-A resided in.

Comment: No detail on the actual hardware makes and models involved? Wouldn't that be useful information?

Comment: @ewwhite PRIMERGY RX4770 M1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using a hardware RAID controller, HDD-B will almost certainly be recognized as a "foreign" drive if you're using enterprise class hardware (which should be fair to assume according to the proper scope of SF questions). Hardware RAID controllers write unique identifying data to distinguish between drives from other controllers. Even if you were able to get an identical copy of data and metadata from HDD-A in its current state written to HDD-B, the second drive would still be treated as either a foreign or failed disk after HDD-A had been removed (assuming system is powered up at the time).
It should be completely safe (again, assuming Enterprise grade RAID controller due to lack of detail provided) to swap out the drives, clear the configuration on HDD-B from whatever management tool you have available (or from the BIOS level after a reboot), and take whatever actions needed to begin a rebuild to the drive.
Side note, there's nothing "safe" about RAID 5 to begin with. If any of the remaining disks encounter any bad blocks during the rebuild, the resulting URE events could result in data corruption, or even a rebuild failure. Please consider getting a validated backup of any data you don't already have protected before swapping disks around if at all possible... And consider using RAID10 or RAID6 next time around if losing the system's data concerns you enough to ask the community about it, both types are MUCH more fault tolerant.

Comment: Yes, enterprise class hardware is in use here. Thanks for all the details!

Answer (score 0):

You maybe need to reinitialize the drive (delete the metadata of the former Raid group) on HDD-B. Afterwards the controller (or md) does not care, what was written on the disks and will consider this it as empty.